# Binding a TreeView control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C# to bind a tree view control in my application. The following code is used in WinForms, but it's not working in WebForms. Can someone help to convert this to WebForms?

```
private TreeNode AddNode(TreeNode node, string key)
{
    if (node.Nodes.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return node.Nodes[key];
    }
    else
    {
        return node.Nodes.Add(key, key);
    }
}
```

I want to implement the same logic. In WebForms we do not have method `node.nodes`, or `node.nodes.Containskey()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tree web control there is [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.value.aspx) property, which can be used to store application data. But you have to manage it by yourself. Your code should look like this:

```
private TreeNode AddNode(TreeNode node, string key)
{
  val child = node.ChildNodes.Cast<TreeNode>().FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Value == key);
  if(child != null)
     return child;

  child = new TreeNode(key, key);
  node.ChildNodes.Add(child);
  return child;
}
```

Comment: right, you have ChildNodes. Anyway MSDN is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3xb205.aspx